# Prove $\sigma_V=x\sigma_S$. (Financial Mathematics)

Tags: finance, mathematical-modeling

Prove that the standard deviation of the value $V(T)$ at time of any portfolio $(x,y)$ at time $T$ in a one-step binomial is given by $\sigma_V=x\sigma_S$, where $\sigma_S$ is the standard deviation of the stock value at time $T$.

I know we should use the property of the expectation and the variance to do this but I have no idea where to start. Can someone help me please?

Comment: It might be helpful, if you would explain all the variables, indices and terms. More detailed information about the general issue would be helpful as well.

Comment: $S(T)$ stands for the price of the stock at time $T$ and $A(T)$ stands for the price of bonds at time $T$. $V(T)$ stands for the value of the portfolio. $V(T) = xS(T) +yV(T)$.

Comment: I don´t think, that this additional information are sufficient enough so that a non-business student can offer helpful tips. If you want change your original post, you can edit it. It is a little bit confusung, that you mentioned $A(T)$ in the last post, which is not mentioned in the original post.

Comment: @jinha0001 basically, you need to confirm whether $V(T)=xS(T)+yA(T)$ and add this relation to your text. Note that your previous comment has a typo: you use $V(T)$ twice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:
$${\rm Var}\left[V(T) \right] = {\rm Var}\left[xS(T)+yA(T) \right] $$ $$=x^2{\rm Var}\left[S(T) \right] + y^2{\rm Var}\left[A(T) \right] + 2xy{\rm Cov}\left[A(T),S(T)\right]$$

You appear to be assuming that $A(T)$ is deterministic, that is, ${\rm Var}\left[A(T) \right]=0$ and ${\rm Cov}\left[A(T),S(T)\right]=0$. This will indeed lead to 
$$ \sigma_{V(T)} = |x| \sigma_{S(T)}.$$